# trying to post file to php server using python and requests

Tags: php, python, python-requests

I am trying to emulate this java code

```
            public static void uploadFile(String filename, String systemID){
            try{
                    String createNew = "false";

                    //check for backup files to know if we should make a new file on the server
                    File f = new File(filename + ".1");
                    if(f.exists()){
                            createNew = "true";
                            f.delete();
                    }

                    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(uploadURL).openConnection();
            httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
            java.io.OutputStream os = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            String fileData = IOUtils.toString(new FileReader(filename));

            String request = "filedata=" + fileData + "&filename=" + filename + "&systemid=" + systemID + "&createNew=" + createNew;

            DeflaterOutputStream deflate = new DeflaterOutputStream(os);
            deflate.write(request.getBytes());
            deflate.flush();
            deflate.close();

            os.close();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream()));

            String s = null;
            while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            in.close();
            //fis.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            static String uploadURL = "http://vp-creations.com/utilities/fileupload.php";
```

in python using requests, I think im missing something simple because I havent been able to get the right response from the server

```
import requests
url = 'http://vp-creations.com/utilities/fileupload.php'
files = {'file': open('C:\\etc\\guitartab.txt', 'rb')}
headers = {'Content-encoding': 'deflate', 'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream'}

payload = {'filedata=': 'foo', 'filename=': 'bar', 'systemid=' : 'fooe', 'createNew=' : 'false'}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

the response from the server that I keep getting is
{"response":"error","comment":"missing at least one parameter"}'
any help please?

Comment: What happens if you do `'createNew=' : 'true'`?

Comment: Also, have you verified that the java code is working?

Comment: yup the java code works, i have been using it for weeks now, and I tried true, still didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a dictionary to the `data` parameter of `requests.post`, it will be form-encoded. I'm not totally familiar with the Java code, but it looks like it is actually using an encoded `String` as the data of the request. In order to achieve the same thing with `requests`, pass a string as the `data` parameter, like so:

```
data = 'filedata=foo&filename=bar&systemid=&fooe&createNew=false'
r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers, data=data)
```

See a similar example in the documentation [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Comment: that didnt exactly work but i changed payload to
`payload = {'filedata': 'foo', 'systemid' : 'fooe', 'createNew' : 'false', 'filename': 'bar'}`


and then i used this but it still didnt work

`r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers, params=payload)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to try changing the following things.

Firstly, `data` sends the given dictionary in the POST body. If that is genuinely where you want it, you need to remove the '=' elements from the dictionary:

```
payload = {'filedata': 'foo', 'filename': 'bar', 'systemid' : 'fooe', 'createNew' : 'false'}
```

Secondly, you're adding a pair of incorrect headers. When you use Requests' `file` parameter, Requests prepares the body data (including your file) as `multipart/form-data'`. You then override that Content-Type with your `application/octet-stream`, which is *not* the form of the body. Additionally, you are claiming that your body data is compressed using `deflate`, which it is not.

Try the following code:

```
import requests
url = 'http://vp-creations.com/utilities/fileupload.php'
files = {'file': open('C:\\etc\\guitartab.txt', 'rb')}

payload = {'filedata': 'foo', 'filename': 'bar', 'systemid' : 'fooe', 'createNew' : 'false'}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=payload)
```

Comment: tried that, still didnt work. Got the same error as before. I figured that i needed those headers b/c they were included in the java file